# why grunt serve copies no more existing files into html

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I'm using yeoman, and when i use grunt serve, scripts that I have removed from app/scripts folder are included in th HTML.

How to fix this please ?

Comment: It is impossible to answer you without more information. Which yeoman generator did you use ? Describe in details what you have done and what is happening.

Comment: I have used angular-generator. But actually I want to remove external libraries, not scripts from angular like controller, services ...

Answer (score 0):

Probably [grunt-bower-install](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install). Make sure `bower.json` is accurate with the dependencies of your application. If you're having too much trouble, you can disable the `grunt-bower-install` task (uninstall and remove references in `Gruntfile.js`).

Comment: This is for librairies installed via bower I suppose. But i'm talking about libraries not installed via bower which are in app/scripts repository

Comment: Ah, then this answer won't help.